# Elementary proof of cannonball problem: why can't $n$ be a multiple of $3$?

Tags: nt.number-theory

At the end of the proof of lemma 10, lemma 8 is cited. In order to use it and finish the contradiction, we need to show $n$ is not a multiple of $3.$ However, I don't see any contradiction in having $n \equiv \pm 2 \mod 8$ and $n \equiv 0 \mod 3.$ I also asked on MSE but not even a halfpenny of thoughts were given.

Proof: [Anglin - The square pyramid puzzle](https://doi.org/10.1080/00029890.1990.11995558).

Comment: The m.se question was https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4557787/elementary-proof-of-cannonball-problem-why-cant-n-be-a-multiple-of-3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lemma 8 is used to conclude that the second factor on the left is $-1$. Note that this factor is
$$
\left( \frac{5}{u_{2^s}}\right)
$$
meaning you apply Lemma 8 for $m=2^s$ and **not** for $n$. It is obvious that $m$ is not a multiple of $3$.

Comment: I didn't notice the superscript, my mistake